# "strnset" is unable to be use in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

"strnset" is standard-c, (visual c++) and should work in objective-c.
But it doesn't recognize it.

What library am I missing?  I have tried: stdio.h and string.h... both don't do it.
what would work in its place where I am given a char array and I want to create: n * characters to be placed in it?

```
example:  _strnset(data, '8', 12); will yield ->    data = "888888888888"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `memset()` instead. `strnset` is not part of the standard "C" library.

What property does `strset` have over `memset` that you are interested in?

```
NAME
     memset -- fill a byte string with a byte value

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS

     #include <string.h>

     void *
     memset(void *b, int c, size_t len);

DESCRIPTION
     The memset() function writes len bytes of value c (converted to an
     unsigned char) to the byte string b.

RETURN VALUES
     The memset() function returns its first argument.
```

Comment: Probably should give instructions on how to use `memset()` to replace `strnset()`, as the semantics are different. :)

Answer (score 1):

`strnset` is actually *not* a standard C function. It's not present in the GCC headers.